# Google app mail hosting and windows 2008 server DNS configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, g-suite, google

I used to use shared hosting before and I created a google app account and I configured DNS records on shared hosting's contol panel according to google dns documentations.

Everything was working until I switched to dedicated server. First I added DNS role to my new server and I configured whole DNS and NS stuff.

I have mail address that mail.domain.com that was redirecting to google app email before. Rightnow, It's not possible to access to mail.domain.com addres from somewhere. But I'm accessing from a few point which located some computer on different network.

I stacked in this problem. Please, see the below screen shots

I checked on DNSStuff.com,everything is green. [image]

Also, I checked on InteliWiz, it seems correct [image]

And, Here is the my DNS records. [image]

I was accessing to my mail.domain.com address from everywhere, Now, I cannot access to mails from many places since 3 weeks.

Where is the my mistake ? 
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MX records you've got setup are for mail routing, and direct (SMTP) mail servers delivering mail to your domain to the right place, they don't direct HTTP clients to the Google Apps service.

If your new DNS server is actually being queried for your domain then it's likely your mail is being routed correctly.

Have you configured the custom URL in Google Apps to match the domain you're using on your DNS server? Instructions from Google are here: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53340

It might help to post the domain for which you're trying to set this up, letting ServerFault know the domain name doesn't compromise your security.

Comment: Thank you, It was helped to me. At least I changed to https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com url. Now, It's working and I will do custom domain alias in short time.